# JQuery: How to Redraw Slider?

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider, redraw, recreate

I need your help desperately since I spent too much time trying to modify Jquery Slider Plugin with no success.

I am using this slider plugin: http://blog.egorkhmelev.com/2010/03/jquery-slider-update/

What I am trying to do is to re-draw this JQuery Slider on click. When user clicks - new settings with new scale and pointer positions are passed. Redraw works only partially, changing only one pointer position and scale. I must have missed something in the code or do not have enough Jquery knowledge to solve this problem.

Please note: Redraw is not yet implemented in this plugin, its a new feature I am trying to add.

A lot of people have asked the same question on official website but it seems that there is no support anymore. So if you could help me to find a bug - I promise to share this solution on the web again.

Thank you a lot!
Kelvin

Comment: That's a pretty neat slider. I think I'm going to use that in a project I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
/* -------- REDRAW SLIDER CODE -------- */
case "redraw":
    //self.domNode.remove(); // remove slider
    self.domNode.remove(); // remove slider
    if (isDefAndNotNull(args[1])) {
        $.extend(true, self.settings, args[1]);
        self.settings.interval = self.settings.to - self.settings.from; //calculate new interval
        self.settings.value = self.inputNode.attr("value"); // set new pointers position
        self.is = {
            init: false
        };
        self.o = {};
        }

    self.create(); // re-create slider with new settings
    break; 
/* -------- END OF REDRAW SLIDER CODE -------- */
```

I just added code to clear out some internal state `self.is.init` and `self.o`.

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ZEjSv/

Comment: is `self` a build in keyword such as `this`? or is it a locally set variable that is referencing the slider?

Comment: It's locally set: `var self = $.slider(this, action);`

Comment: @Nick self is a local variable: var self = this;